# OBIEE 12.2.1.2 - Application Roles and Policies

Tags: oracle, permissions, roles, business-intelligence, obiee

I am facing problems with application roles and policies in the latest OBIEE release.

I have successfully migrated from OBIEE 11.xx to OBIEE 12.1.2.2 (without the roles, since they were a bit messed up in 11)

1. Creating "clean" roles and implementing/editing in the EM works just fine.
2. Connecting roles to an Active Directory works.
3. Changing privileges works at first glance.
4. However, the roles are not inheriting characteristics as expected resulting in quite a (working) mess again.

I have tried to illustrate the problem, see [appendix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeVNe.png)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Max,
You say "Access for a BIContentAuthor only works" - which access do you mean? I get your inheritance chart but I don't understand what exactly isn't working.
I've done tons of security configurations since 12 came out and am wondering what's happening for you there.

Comment: Hi Christian, I am talking about the access to a poweruser role, in this case to answers/specific folder.

One more example would be: removing the right to see the obiee homepage from a consumer also removes it from biadmin –however- both roles are not combined in EM and/or Active Directory. The transparency behind the privilege structure is somehow difficult to grasp.